# Login Form in C# windows Presentation Foundation

Tags: c#, wpf

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        OleDbConnection MyCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Project.accdb");

        public string user;
        string password;
        public string name;
        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            user = textBox1.Text;
            char firstLetter = user[0];
            string password = textBox2.Text;
            MyCon.Open();
            string command = "Select * from Login where userid=@userid AND password = @password";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(command, MyCon);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@user, textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@password, textBox2.Text);
            OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (dr.Read() == true)
                {

                    Window1 w1 = new Window1();

                    w1.textBox3.Text = user;
                    string Name = w1.textBox4.Text;
                    string Command = "Select Name from Login ";
                    OleDbCommand cms = new OleDbCommand(Command, MyCon);
                    cms.Parameters.AddWithValue(@Name, w1.textBox4.Text);
                    OleDbDataReader odr = cms.ExecuteReader();

                    w1.Show();
                    this.Close();

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("NOt Login");
                }
```

This is my coding in C# windows presentation foundation. I make a Login form in C# WPFmm. If Any user to enter ID and Pasword so open new Form. And user see only your name. How can i access only his user name those enter correct id and passord?

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question?  It is very hard to understand what exactly you need help with.  If English is not your first language, you can use [google translate](http://translate.google.com).

Comment: yar me ye krna chahta ho ke ke koi bi user apna id and pasword de to us ke pas new form open ho ga,, And us pe usi bnde ka name ho ga,,

Comment: i want to do that any user login window his id and password then new form will open and his name will appear on that window.

Comment: @ShaniBaba You are closing the main window, that closes the application, dont do that, hide it instead

Answer (score 2):

Closing the MainWindow will kill the application, as it stores the main thread (main method), instead of `this.Close();` use `this.Hide();` and your code should work assuming your database connection is correct.

Anyway [here](http://bit.ly/HerHJj) is a very very quick example I wrote in WPF to help you understand passing parameters from one window to another correctly.